# How to make the Class that implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar work properly when depends on other beans?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm writing my own lib - try to impl annotation-driven distributied lock on Redisson

My demands `Enable* mode` and `Muti-Source`, so I define my annotation and use `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` to achieve. Here the code

The Enable* mode Annotation

```
// omit others
@Import({RLockAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public @interface EnableRLock {
}
```

The AutoConfiguration

```
// omit others
@Configuration
public class RLockAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RLockParser rLockParser() {
        return new RLockParser();
    }

    @Bean
    public RLockRegister rLockRegister(RLockParser parser) {
        return new RLockRegister(parser);
    }
}
```

The Parser ( to read properties and converto Config )

```
public class RLockParser implements EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment environment;
    // parse result
    private RLockProperty property;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
        // parse and convert
    }

    // omit other
}
```

And the last Class implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar

```
public class RLockRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
    private RLockParser parser;
        
    @Autowired
    public RLockRegistrar(RLockParser parser) {
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        // generate bean-definitions for each source
    }

    // omit others
}
```

Then, things became strangely. I start up the app in debug and set breakpoint in `registerBeanDefinitions` methods, and I was suprised that the app run directly and the breakpoint invalid, I think may be the `RLockRegistrar` is not registered but it can be get through `context.getBean(RLockRegistrar.class)`, also the bean `rLockParser` inject into it

I totally don't know what to do, at the begin, RLockRegistrar and RLockParser were code of the same class working properly. I extracted the code, and it turned out not working.

why can't and how to resolve

Comment: An `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` cannot depend on other beans as it is not operating on a full application context on a `BeanDefinitionRegister` to add beandefinitions.